# Can't find Tomcat in STS

Tags: maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I am going through a tutorial to build a web based application using Spring Boot and I am using Spring Tool Suite for the same.

I have created a basic entity, its corresponding JPA Repository, Service POJOs, a Controller.

This is the pom.xml

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Issue:

As per the tutorial, when the project is Run As -> Spring Boot App, tomcat server starts and the corresponding logs are displayed in the console.

But, when I run it the same way(Spring Boot App), I don't see any Tomcat server running. And the process is terminated. If I access localhost:8080, it obviously shows me This site can't be reached.

I have run Maven -> Clean and Maven -> Install.

What am I missing to do here?

Update:

I deleted the .m2 folder, Maven -> Clean and Maven -> Install. Exited STS, ran it again. And voila, everything works like a charm. Not a single error. Magic? I don't know.

Comment: Good first question! It’s intelligible, you tried to solve it yourself, you show clearly what you tried. Most first questions are not this good.

Comment: The question is: What are you running exactly by which command ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have mentioned it in the problem statement. Run As -> Spring Boot App.

Comment: This was the first one..but the second one you wrote: `But, when I run it, I don't see any Tomcat server running....` So the issue is that you are trying to run it as a Java application the whole part around it (Spring boot is missing) which causes the issue. This is the difference of running a spring boot app via `java -jar SpringBootAppPackaged.jar`(there are two jar files being created in the `target` director ) and trying to run the other one which does not contain the spring boot starter part....

Comment: @khmarbaise I thought it was implied that I was running it as Sprint Boot App. Will edit the question.

Comment: Do you get an error message on the console if you start it a second time? Have you stopped the first run ?

Comment: @khmarbaise first run or any further runs terminate automatically.

Comment: Please take a look into the console and post the log output here or via some link...

Comment: @khmarbaise I deleted the .m2 file, I run Maven -> Clean and Maven -> Install. Exited STS, ran it again. And voila, everything works like a charm. Not a single error. Magic? I don't know. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I assume you had some download/network/firewall issues otherwise this can't be explained...So I recommend to turn on checksum policy in your settings.xml file (also in Eclipse)...

Comment: @khmarbaise something like this?    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <createChecksum>true</createChecksum>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
I am talking about the <configuration> tag

Comment: No in the settings.xml see here: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the .m2 folder, run Maven -> Clean and Maven -> Install. Exited STS, ran it again. And voila, everything works like a charm. Not a single error. Magic? I don't know.